# Creating an android native level application using .h and.c file?

Tags: android, native, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Is there any way to use an .h , .c and .so file and also create an android native level application???

Plz Help

Regards

### Heading

Comment: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html).